# Flutter firestore pagination doesn't start after a document,

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement a pagination feature on my list and I've been following this official documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Here is a main code:

```
  Future<List<Review>> fetchReviewPaginated(int limit) async {
    var ref = _firestore.collection('reviews').orderBy('creationDate', descending: true);

    if (_isFetchingUser) return null;

    _isFetchingUser = true;

    if (cachedReview == null) {
      var snapshot = await ref.limit(limit).get();
      lastPage = snapshot.docs.last;
      cachedReview = snapshot.docs.map((e) => Review.fromMap(e.data())).toList();
    } else {
      var snapshot = await ref.startAfter(lastPage["creationDate"]).limit(limit).get();
      lastPage = snapshot.docs.last;
      cachedReview.addAll(snapshot.docs.map((e) => Review.fromMap(e.data())).toList());
    }
    if (cachedReview.length < limit) hasNext = false;

    _isFetchingUser = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return cachedReview;
  }
```

My widget will call `fetchReviewPaginated(5)` and display what is in `cachedReviews`. If the `cachedReviews` is null, then it will fetch 5 of reviews, then it will `startAfter` what is in the last of the `cachedReviews` and get another 5 documents after that point.

Problem is that this function always returns the same 5 items and doesn't truly start after what I specify,

Comment: I've changed it to this `var snapshot = await ref.startAfterDocument(lastPage).limit(limit).get();` and how it works! I tried this approach before and i didnt work before

Comment: Good to hear that works Brendon.    When you have the full `DocumentSnapshot` available, it's always best to pass that to the pagination methods - as they can find both the `timestamp` (or whatever fields you ordered on) *and* the document ID from it, as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test/try your code at this moment but I think this is because `startAfter(lastPage["creationDate"])` is not correct.

You need to pass a **list of values** to `startAfter()` (a list with a unique item in your case). Since `lastPage` is a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) you therefore need to use `get()` or `data()`, like `startAfter([lastPage.get("creationDate")])`.

---

Note that you could instead use the [`startAfterDocument()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/startAfterDocument.html) method to which you pass the `DocumentSnapshot` itself. It is somehow more adapted to your case, since you have only one sorting.